# How can I do to make my app responsive to all phones? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

im new in react-native and im now using expo to taste my app, but I have a problem, is that the app takes all the screen:

[image]

how can I do to make it "responsive for all phones? because Im using two phones to taste it, a one plus 7 pro and a huawei p9 plus, so the one plus is bigger than the huawei, so `marginTop: 20` isnt the same from a one plus and a huawei, the samethig with the button, in the one plus looks like that and huawei it dissapear, because its style is:

```
view: {
  position: "absolute",
  marginLeft: 320,
  marginTop: 550,
}
```

so, it isnt the same, but in the emulator of android studio eveything looks great haha

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Dimensions" to get screen properties and make elements properties proportional

[Dimensions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions)

Comment: ok, but using dimensions and getting them, how I used in the styles? thats what I dont know

Comment: you can put values of Dimensions on const and use this const as values on the styles